# How to stop a Python script executing immediately

Tags: python

I have a python script (script.py) with a bunch of functions, and then a main() function that runs everything.

After the main(), I also have:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am now writing a separate script (timer.py) to run script.py every day at midnight.

```
import schedule
import time
from script import main

schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(main(),'It is 00:00')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60) # wait one minute
```

But when I run it, the main seems to run immediately. I thought that the `if` condition above would prevent that from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Which `if` condition do you mean? Anyhow, instead of calling `main`, pass it to the scheduler's `do()` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change to `main()` to `main` and remove string `'It is 00:00'` because `main()` has no arguments:

```
schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(main)
```

because in your code you **call** `main()` and try scheduling the result of a call (which is probably `None`), while you need to pass `callable` to scheduler.

Comment: I see. I had already tried that, but I got the error: TypeError: main() takes no arguments (1 given). But the script works fine when I try to run it directly.

Comment: Remove argument `'It is 00:00'` if your `main()` function does not accept args

Answer (score 2):

You call ‘main()’ method instead of passing a reference to the ‘main’ function.

Shouldn’t it be like this instead.
   `schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(main,'It is 00:00')`